# Help with pairs of two digit numbers such that the sum is 83

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Can anyone  help me find all pairs of two digit numbers such that the sum is $83$

Comment: You mean 10 and 73, 11 and 72, ... until 41 and 42?

Comment: $(i,j)$ with $i+j=83$ and $i=10,11,\cdots,41$.

Comment: @Bram28 yes ,all of them

Comment: @prayersmith Not sure what your question is .. You just want to see all of them?

Comment: Yes please @Bram28

Comment: @prayersmith I'm sure you can do this yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(10,\; 73),\; (11,\; 72),\; (12,\; 71),\; (13,\; 70),\; (14,\; 69),\; (15,\; 68),\; (16,\; 
  67),\; (17,\; 66),\; (18,\; 65),\; (19,\; 64),\; (20,\; 63),\; (21,\; 62),\; (22,\; 
  61),\; (23,\; 60),\; (24,\; 59),\; (25,\; 58),\; (26,\; 57),\; (27,\; 56),\; (28,\; 
  55),\; (29,\; 54),\; (30,\; 53),\; (31,\; 52),\; (32,\; 51),\; (33,\; 50),\; (34,\; 
  49),\; (35,\; 48),\; (36,\; 47),\; (37,\; 46),\; (38,\; 45),\; (39,\; 44),\; (40,\; 
  43),\; (41,\; 42),\; (42,\; 41),\; (43,\; 40),\; (44,\; 39),\; (45,\; 38),\; (46,\; 
  37),\; (47,\; 36),\; (48,\; 35),\; (49,\; 34),\; (50,\; 33),\; (51,\; 32),\; (52,\; 
  31),\; (53,\; 30),\; (54,\; 29),\; (55,\; 28),\; (56,\; 27),\; (57,\; 26),\; (58,\; 
  25),\; (59,\; 24),\; (60,\; 23),\; (61,\; 22),\; (62,\; 21),\; (63,\; 20),\; (64,\; 
  19),\; (65,\; 18),\; (66,\; 17),\; (67,\; 16),\; (68,\; 15),\; (69,\; 14),\; (70,\; 
  13),\; (71,\; 12),\; (72,\; 11),\; (73,\; 10)$

```
(10, 73), (11, 72), (12, 71), (13, 70), (14, 69), (15, 68),
(16, 67), (17, 66), (18, 65), (19, 64), (20, 63), (21, 62), 
(22, 61), (23, 60), (24, 59), (25, 58), (26, 57), (27, 56), 
(28, 55), (29, 54), (30, 53), (31, 52), (32, 51), (33, 50), 
(34, 49), (35, 48), (36, 47), (37, 46), (38, 45), (39, 44), 
(40, 43), (41, 42), (42, 41), (43, 40), (44, 39), (45, 38), 
(46, 37), (47, 36), (48, 35), (49, 34), (50, 33), (51, 32), 
(52, 31), (53, 30), (54, 29), (55, 28), (56, 27), (57, 26), 
(58, 25), (59, 24), (60, 23), (61, 22), (62, 21), (63, 20), 
(64, 19), (65, 18), (66, 17), (67, 16), (68, 15), (69, 14), 
(70, 13), (71, 12), (72, 11), (73, 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just ... do them.

$a + b = 83$ so $b = 83 - a$ and $a \ge 10$

So

$a = 10,11,12,.........,71,72,73$

and $b = 73,72,71,.........,12,11,10$.

Answer (score 1):

Im bored

$
\\10, 73
\\11, 72
\\12, 71
\\13, 70
\\14, 69
\\15, 68
\\16, 67
\\17, 66
\\18, 65
\\19, 64
\\20, 63
\\21, 63
\\22, 61
\\23, 60
\\24, 59
\\25, 58
\\26, 57
\\27, 56
\\28, 55
\\29, 54
\\30, 53
\\31, 52
\\32, 51
\\33, 50
\\34, 49
\\35, 48
\\36, 47
\\37, 46
\\38, 45
\\39, 44
\\40, 43
\\41, 42
\\ 93, -10
\\ 94, -11
\\ 95, -12
\\96, -13
\\97, -14
\\98, -15
\\99, -16
$